# Is it safe to use jku, kid and x5u in JSON Web Signature (JWS) header?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, jwt

I don't get what header parameters like `jku`, `kid`, `x5u` are for in JSON Web Signature (JWS).

Since We have to verify the integrity of the content against secret key/public key, is it safe to leave `jku`, `kid`, `x5u` in the JWS header? Someone may replace these sections by their own and sign a new signature with his key against the tampered content. So how do we deal with such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These fields are here to allow the component verifying the ticket to identify the key used for the signature.

- `jku` is an URI that reference the public key used for generating the signature. It must follow [RFC7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) format. The entity verifying the token is responsible for checking whether that signing key can be trusted or not.
- `kid` is the key identification and it's only valid in the context of a given audience: the context of your application must define how to use that parameter to identify the key. It can be the fingerpring of the x509 cert user for signing, it can be the certificat serial number, it can be a reference to a row in a table, it can be the ID of a HMAC secret stored into a JSON file, or the XPath inside a XML document, whatever is defined by the signing party.
- `x5u` must contain an URL to the x509 certificate that was used for signing the token. That certificate must be in [PEM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) format.

Typically, you will only have one of these parameters in any given token (there can only be one signing key, after all) although it isn't impossible to have the same key accessible through different methods (this mostly means that it's not impossible to have both a jku and a x5u header that point to the same key but you should try to avoid that kind of ambiguity).

By definition, if someone changes the headers and signs the ticket again, *the result is not the same token* so you don't need to worry about that: you can safely reject any token that you can't properly validate.

Comment: In this case: X signs a signature for content Z with private key, Y receives the content and verify it with public key. If the signature and the public key clue inside JWS header both get changed, how could Y validate it and reject?

Comment: Y doesn't care where the headers comes from: it must read the headers and see if it can use them for validating the signature. if it cannot (because it doesn't understand the parameters), it must reject the token. if it can but the signature doesn't match (because a different key was used for signing) it must reject the token. Otherwise, it must accept it.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something fundamental: a token is immutable. You can't slice it into parts and rebuild it. If you do, it is a different token and you must sign it again.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to use the JWT headers to carry information that isn't actually related to the token itself? Know that you're not allowed to do that: anything that isn't directly related to the token itself must be in the body.

Comment: From what I know, JWS is composed of <header>.<payload>.<signature>  .  <signature> is private_key(<header>.<payload>) . I could change the header and use my own private key to generate signature, then send <modified header>.<modified payload>.<modified signature> to X. Then if X use the public key listed in <modified header> to verify, he'll take it as valid. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Or should the receiver know the public key before? Then why these parameters needed?

Comment: If you modify the header, your create a new, different token even if the payload stay the same. In effect, you're changing the authority of the token. Put it like that: it's like if you received a signed mail from someone, copy the content into a new message, signe it and send it to someone else: the new recipient will have no way of verifying that the data your forwarding came from the original source.

Comment: Sorry, the comments above should be Y instead of X. Also, if someone didn't change the structure but just the value of the header, Y still understand the parameters.

Comment: It's still not the same signature: it must be signed again. Once more. you CANNOT treat a signed the token as made of different parts: you MUST treat is as a single entity. Any change turns it into a different token. This isn't optional or negotiable

Comment: So the basic question is: under what condition should we use JWS? Isn't JWS for integrity? If someone in the middle changed the message from X, also changed the signature accordingly. How could Y tell if it's unchanged only by the header's indication?

Comment: It's like, the file, the gpg key and the fingerprint are all modified. How could you tell it's the right file?

Comment: @whuala I think you missed when Stephane said in his answer: `The entity verifying the token is responsible for checking whether that signing key can be trusted or not.` See also https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7515#section-10.3

Comment: @whuala Are you sure you understand the base of what digital signature is about? If you do, then I can't make sense out of your question.